# the right way to require sass dependencies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation in my Rails project, and I'm having difficulties with including foundation scss files in my project. I want to be able to use variables from `foundation_and_overrides` in different scss files but if I require this file using @import in each scss file, it appears that foundation will be included multiple times in my project.

My stylesheet structure is the following:

**application.css.css:**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require pages
 */

@import "foundation_and_overrides";
```

**pages.css.css:**

```
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
```

The problem is if I don't import `foundation_and_overrides` in `pages.css.scss` I won't be able to use foundation predefined variables, such `$primary-color`.

The question is: how should I use require or sass import function correctly, so that Rails will compile foundation only once and I will be able to use foundation variables in all scss files?

Comment: The foundation generator actually creates the foundation_and_overrides file for you, so you can modify it as you wish and import it once in your `application.css.scss`.

Comment: Can we come up with a better title for this question?  Best I could come up with is "Importing Sass file with Rails without code duplication", but I'm not certain that accurately describes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use [`@import`](http://sass-lang.com/guide) directives at the root level, instead of using `require`. The `@import` directives are controlled by the SCSS processor so everything should then be in scope for use in any SCSS file. For example:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

@import "defines";
@import "foundation_and_overrides";

@import "base";
@import "forms";
```

You can put any variable/mix-in definitions you want to be global to your app in the defines.css.scss file and then have foundation_and_overrides.css.scss use these if you'd like. Otherwise, any file defined after foundation_and_overrides.css.scss (in source/line order) should now have access to all the foundation variables (as well as your own defines).

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good practice to use @import instead of require for all dependencies? Or should I use it just in some cases?

Comment: I use it in all cases. I don't know any reason it'd be bad.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry code inclusion has broken on SO (thus code seems a little wierd )

My way for all apps

1. Not to rename application.css to application.scss (and same for
   application.js not to rename to application.coffee)
2. For scss files to create directories
3. then require directories recursively by:

```
# application.css
*/
 *= require_tree ./directory_name
*/
```

```
# application.js

#= require_tree ./directory_name
```

4. For TwitterBootstrap / ZurbFondation create
    `shared/bootstrap-init.scss` `include @import 'bootstrap';` files in
    it.
 5. Then require the files in manifest file:

```
# application.css
*/
 *= require_tree ./shared
*/
```